# How to get meta tag content in ganon?

Tags: html, dom, html-parsing, meta, ganon

How to get meta tag content in [ganon](https://code.google.com/p/ganon/)?
Tryed this doesn't work.

```
foreach($html('meta[name="keywords"]') as $keywords ) {
    echo $keywords->plaintext();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($html('meta[name="keywords"]') as $keywords ) {
    echo $keywords->content;
}
```